# Merging 2 records in a view into single record - SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2012

I have a view which has records derived from multiple tables.

[Sample data below in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUxk.jpg)

I have to merge the above 2 records into single record as below in the image while retrieving the records from the view. Any suggestions on this will be really helpful

[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJXOd.jpg)

To add further information :
There is a table A which has the data that should not be edited. So if any new data needs to be addeded/modified, it will be keyed from front end and stored in two different tables B & C depending on the screen. So there is chance of mismatch between the user data (Name, Gender, DOB etc) keyed and the data stored in table B & C and the table A. I have created a view that will cross check the data in 2 tables (table B & C) with data in a common table (table A) separately & union them. If there is mismatch in data between table A and B or Table A and C, column Issue_In_table1 or Issue_In_Table2 will be hardcoded as true/false based on which table has mismatched data. There is a chance of both having same mismatched data only with data difference in columns Issue_In_table1 and Issue_In_Table2 (Yes or No alternatively). So, instead having 2 different records for same mismatched data, I need to have single record with both Issue_In_table1 and Issue_In_Table2 as yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
id, company_code, ROLE, seq_number, country, TYPE,
first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender, dob,
MAX([issue IN TABLE 1]),
MAX([issue IN TABLE 2])
FROM
VIEW
GROUP BY
id, company_code, ROLE, seq_number, country, TYPE,
first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender, dob
```

not sure how your True/False values are stored, if they're text or numeric, but if it's masking the Trues instead of the Falses, try `MIN()` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying different things and nothing worked out. It really saved a lot of time for me